# Spring OAuth2 API combine password grant AND third-party provider

Tags: spring, api, oauth, oauth-provider

I'm looking for a solution to add third-party provider OAuth2 flow like Facebook to my existing Spring OAuth2 authorization server and resource server using Spring Security which accept only password grant actually.

This work great with `/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypwd`

Now, I need to understand how I can add provider OAuth flow, I tried many tutorials with Spring Social for example or with Filter to catch request but.. it's never for only API and/or never coupled with password grant and can't found how to do this, maybe I miss something ?

**Again it's only for API, no need configure route /login? or so**

If someone can explain me how to do this or github/tutorial example project ? Spring Social can help me here ?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Do you want to implement a client (i.e. your application will act as a client and FB is the auth provider)?

Comment: Hm sry thinking that was clear, not really, I want to add to my oauth server the possibility to authenticate and authorize a user from third-party provider.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is Spring Social. There's a sample app. I haven't it tried it myself but you can find it here: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook.git